# How to display a background image with a:hover

Tags: css, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/gUckp/

In the above demo, I'd like to show an orange round image BELOW the center of menu item when it is hovered.

However I am not able to show all the image. The bottom is cut.

How can I do it with CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `display:inline;` on the `li` items, the `height` attribute you've given is ignored. Put the `:hover` on the `li` items istead of the `a` tags and it works. The `height` and `line-height` you've used becomes superfluous.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pille/gUckp/17/)

Answer (score 2):

Your a tag needs a block specification.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gUckp/16/.

Note the line `display: inline-block;` for the `#nav a` class.

The reason for the image not displaying correctly in your sample is because it was being placed outside of the a tag rendered block size.

**EDIT**

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) helps tremendously in resolving these types of issues. It allows you to inspect elements etc. I'd suggest adding it to your development toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: #01291e url(http://demo.chevereto.com/images/hoverorang.png) no-repeat 50%;
```

See [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUckp/1/).

**Edit:** O sorry, that's not what you asked for. Will try again... ;)

**Edit 2:** Hereby the [correct one](http://jsfiddle.net/gUckp/19/).

**Edit 3:** [Or this one with a nicer focusrect size](http://jsfiddle.net/gUckp/22/). Enjoy!